# Mongoose - Defining a model for a preexisting collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have imported some CSV data to my database through mongoimport, which created my collection during the import.

When defining my model in Node, what do I pass for the schema parameter? Viewing my db in compass shows a schema already created based off the imported data.

I'm currently passing an empty schema which seems totally wrong.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Units = new Schema({
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Units', Units, 'units');
```

Comment: That should work, what error do you have?

Comment: No error, asking if this is correct practice when using preexisting data in my db. Seems pointless passing an empty Schema

Comment: You can add the fields of your documents to your Schema, e.g., if your documents consists of: _id, username and email, you can do: var Units = new Schema({ _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, username: String, email: String });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema should contain something like this that defines the kind of data you're working with.

```
var Units = new Schema({
    f_name: String,
    l_name: String,
    manager: Boolean
});
```

See ['Defining your schema'](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Also, I don't believe mongoose.model takes a third parameter.

`module.exports = mongoose.model('Units',Units);`

**Edit:** [yes it does.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model)

Comment: That third parameter signifies the MongoDB collection to use for that model ([doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model))

Comment: Ah, you're right: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model